# Javascript Stored Date Between Timezones

Tags: javascript, datetime, react-native

I've been looking for a solution to this but as yet I've not found exactly what I'm looking for. I have the following issue:

A user selects a time in my react-native app. I store this in an SQLite DB as a `datetime`.

The user can edit said stored time and the DB is updated.

When the user selects a time from the input, a date is constructed from it and the time is outputted on-screen to show their selection after dismissing the input.

This all works OK if my user is in one timezone.

Unfortunately, if the user were to travel to another timezone the DB value is adjusted and the wrong time is displayed on the edit screen.

---

So, if I select the following on my form: `7:00am`

My DB will store (for example) `Sun Oct 01 2017 07:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST)`

If however, I move my timezone to Tokyo and edit the time in my app, it is adjusted and shows a different value to `7:00am`.

Here is the code I use to construct the date that is passed into the DB:

`var date = new Date(Date.parse('2017-10-01T' + hours + ':' + mins + ':00Z'));
var _ofst = date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;
date = date.getTime() + _ofst;`

*(where `date` is stored)*

Now, I know the offset is going to skew things but if I don't use it, my on-screen feedback to the user is adjusted to `8:00am` due to my local current timezone.

What I want to do:

As an example, when a user selects 7:00am:

- it should show this on screen correctly when a user picks a time (e.g. `7:00am`)
- it should store this in the DB correctly (Sun Oct 01 2017 07:00:00)
- if the user moves timezone, I don't want it to adjust the stored value. (I want `7:00am` to be the time used in-app)

I know I could use string manipulation to extract the stored time from the DB and re-construct the date on the way out but I am wondering if there is a less hacky approach which will maintain the chosen time regardless of where the user is in the world.

I want to use this time for notifications so if a user picks 7:00am they should see the notification at 7:00am.

---

### Update

I think I've found a good way to manage this using `moment.js` which handily is part of `node_modules` in React-Native.

By using:
`var date = moment('2017-10-01T' + hours + ':' + mins + ':00Z').utc().format();`

I can ensure that the date stored in my DB is: 
`2017-10-01T07:00:00Z`

This means it isn't 'polluted' by any offset data and when I bring it back out of the db I can use the same `moment` code to recreate my non-offset datetime.

Initial tests are proving successful using this method. All hail `moment.js`!

Answer (score 1):

You are way overthinking things here.

If you don't want the time to adjust for timezone.. simply don't adjust.
A timezone anchors your time to a geographic location.  You don't want that.

Store the selected time (e.g. `7:00 am`) without a timezone, and just compare it to the local time.

Comment: Thanks - I've actually found a good way of handling things using moment.js - see update above